# SOQL:How to query the Upserted data that has been modified or inserted in every one hour

Tags: apex, soql

We have to verify Data for Upserted action in sandbox. We have scheduled job Using data migration tool which is running hourly basis. and basically Outputting the  data in SFDC target.

**we tried following query :**

```
  Select Id, lastModifiedDate,SystemModstamp from Account where (HOUR_IN_DAY(SystemModstamp)>=1) AND (SystemModstamp>Yesterday)
```

How can we modify query to do verification of Data After Upsert Action on an hourly basis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below works for me to query for data upserted in the last hour:

```
list<account>acct = [Select Id, lastModifiedDate from Account where (HOUR_IN_DAY(lastModifiedDate)
  >= : (system.now().hour() - 1)) AND (lastModifiedDate > YESTERDAY) ] ;

For(Account a:acct){

    system.debug('account Id = '+ a.Id + ' lastmodified = ' +a.lastModifiedDate);
}
```

You may want to add an orderBy clause to what's returned and possibly fine tune this as until I added the Yesterday part to the WHERE clause, I was getting results for any account modified during that hour range on any date. So, you may pick-up records from the previous day during the same hour time slot.

My recommendation would be to add some logic to determine whether the time is between Midnight and 1:30AM to 2AM. You can use that logic to determine whether to use Today() or Yesterday() in your WHERE clause. Pass that into your query dynamically will eliminate those extra records from the previous day.

You could also add an OrderBy clause as well to help determine when that's happening. I'll leave that part to you to decide if and how to implement.

BTW, `SystemModStamp` didn't seem to want to work in my Dev Org for me, but I had no problems with `LastModifiedDate`. Both are date-time, indexed and should work the same. SystemModStamp may work for you in your org with your ETL tool for your use case, but I wasn't able to get it to work when I tested the query.

**EDIT**

In your situation, since the ETL tool is doing the Upsert as opposed to a User, you'll definitely want to use `SystemModStamp` for your query. When I was testing in my DE, I had to update records manually (no ETL tool), so couldn't test with `SystemModStamp`. From the [Help Docs](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=When-is-SystemModStamp-different-from-LastModifiedDate&language=en_US):

> LastModifiedDate is the date and time when a record was last modified by a user, and SystemModstamp is the date and time when a record was last modified by a user or by an automated process (such as a trigger). In this context,  "trigger" refers to Salesforce code that runs to implement standard functionality, rather than an "Apex trigger".
>
> As a result, LastModifiedDate and SystemModstamp will differ when automated processes update the records, which will happen in the following scenarios (asynchronously in some cases):
>
> a) The archive date is extended to greater than 365 days.
>
> b) An existing picklist value is updated (not replaced with an existing picklist value).
>
> c) A contact's e-mail address is flagged as per the Email Bounce Management configuration.
>
> d) The LastActivityDate field is modified
>
> e) Roll-up summary field is created, which will update all the parent records' SystemModstamp asynchronously. Recalculation will also take place if the Summary Type is updated.

Comment: Thanks for solution But when i am trying to execute apex. Output window is blank  though  checking for UI .It is showing the records.

Comment: here is apex  result from workbench :http://paste.ofcode.org/h2E48mK225dT5da5sTQpjg

Comment: Not certain what you mean by "output window is blank". You have to call up the debug logs to see the results. In your case, since the ETL tool is doing the mods, you'll need to use SystemModStamp instead of LastModifiedDate. See my edited answer.

Comment: Sure we will make try on SystemModStamp . and get back to you. Thanks for info on both the date